# Shell script to show online users

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell, users

I know it's an amateur question.  I need to write a Bash shell script which count how many users are online at the moment on the SSH server.  I need to ignore multiple logins and show the username and the place where they logged in.

Thanks.

Comment: Shell meaning Linux shell?  Which linux shell? "Online atm at the server", how do people log in to your server (ssh, telnet, ftp, etc.)?  That may change things.

Comment: Linux shell, bash shell, SSH logs, i tried with rwho but it show the multiple logins

Comment: If you're interested in showing the location of each login, perhaps you need to reconsider ignoring multiple logins; if I'm connected via SSH to host A from both host B and host C, you can either show me as logged in twice, once from each host, or throw away some information.

Comment: Jeh, It shows all the hosts, that's why I need to ignore multiple logins and show the first host, not all.

Answer (score 1):

This smells like homework but oh well:

```
#!/bin/bash

users=$(users | xargs -n1 | sort -u)
for u in $users; do
    w -h | awk '{print $1 " " $3}' | grep -m1 $u
done
```

Explanation:

First we builds a list of logged in users with the "user" command, and filter out duplicates by putting one on each line (xargs -n) and sorting with uniques filtered (sort -u).

w -h prints a list of all logged in users, we pipe that through awk printing only the desired fields (1 and 3), piping the result through grep to filter all but the user we're looking for on each loop iteration. -m1 ensures it stops after the first match, you could also pipe through 'head -1' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `w` command, which shows who is logged on and what they are doing.

```
mike@magisterial $ w
 12:00:25 up 239 days, 22:40, 18 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
john    pts/1    xx.yy.74.10    09:29    1:34m  0.59s  0.02s sshd: john [priv]
jane    pts/3    xx.yy.74.10    09:44    2:05m  0.38s  0.01s sshd: jane [priv]
mike    pts/4    xx.yy.74.10    09:45    1:10m  0.21s  0.21s -bash
```

In your case, filter the output with grep to return only ssh logins:

`w | grep 'sshd:'`

```
john    pts/1    xx.yy.74.10    09:29    1:34m  0.59s  0.02s sshd: john [priv]
jane    pts/3    xx.yy.74.10    09:44    2:05m  0.38s  0.01s sshd: jane [priv]
```